# Get php return value using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I am having a form which gets value from the user and stores it to the database.
On submitting the form ,it calls the **action.php** file using ajax call.

```
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "action.php",
    data: senData,
    dataType: "JSON",

    success: function(data) {

        $("#name").val("");
        $('.msg').fadeIn(500);
        $('.msg').text("" + data.result + "");

    }

});
```

The values are stored in the database without any errors, but I want to display a notification to the user after submitting the form inside the **msg** div.

In my `action.php` file I have added a `JSON Encode` statement to return a message too.

```
$msg = 'Thanks Yo Yo';
echo json_encode(array("result" => $msg));
```

But it is not working i.e, when I submit the form, it stores the data to the database and the webpage refreshes itself without displaying any message inside the `.msg` div.

Am I doing something wrong and is there a better way to do it??

Comment: your page is not supposed to refresh. right ?

Comment: can you post your complete function, which is making a ajax call?

Comment: Please submit your HTML code as well

Comment: There is no problem with the HTML code or AJAX function, as the data get perfectly stored in the database. I just don't want the page to be refreshed and to display a return message from the PHP inside the msg div.

Comment: Have u tried adding alert(data) inside success in ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the JSON when it is returned to your javascript.

```
// Parse the response to JSON
var res = JSON.Parse(data);
$('.msg').text(res.result);
```

Your code should look like this.

```
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "action.php",
 data: senData,
 dataType: "JSON",

 success: function(data) {
    var res = JSON.Parse(data);
    $("#name").val("");
    $('.msg').fadeIn(500).text(res.result);

 }

});
```